# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "liarse la manta a la cabeza"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, significado, historia, coloquialismos

Hay una expresión en castellano que dice:

> Liarse / echarse la manta a la cabeza

Para mí, se refiere a animarse a hacer algo de un modo algo irreflexivo, del tipo:

> Juan siempre quiso ver mundo, así que finalmente se lió la manta a la
>   cabeza, dejó el trabajo y se dispone a enrolarse en un crucero que da
>   la vuelta al mundo.

Pero me surgen varias dudas al respecto:

- ¿Es "liarse" o "echarse"?
- ¿Se usa en otros países además de España?
- ¿Cuál es su origen?

Comment: El significado no es exactamente el que tú propones. "liarse/echarse la manta a la cabeza" significa hacer (rápidamente) los preparativos para un viaje o, en su defecto, algún tipo de aventura, pero no es necesario que sea de un modo irreflexivo, sino más bien, cogiendo lo necesario y sin perder tiempo. Yo siempre he usado las dos formas: liarse y echarse, y pienso que ambas son correctas. No sé de su origen ni si se utiliza en otros países (soy español por cierto)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la propia definición del Diccionario de la RAE:

> manta1.
>   (De manto).
>
> liarse alguien la ~ a la cabeza.
>   1. loc. verb. Tomar una decisión precipitada o actuar de modo irreflexivo.

Muchas de las frases hechas o refranes españoles vienen heredadas de siglos atrás, así que no descartaría en absoluto que la referencia al Cid Campeador fuera el origen de la expresión.

En cualquier caso, sí que se trata de una decisión irreflexiva, no tanto por irresponsable, sino por precipitada, sin tiempo para reflexionar sobre sus consecuencias.

Comment: Interesante, muchas gracias. No se me había ocurrido mirar en la RAE :)

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a [este artículo](https://lalenguaesagrandesconocida.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/liarse-la-manta-a-la-cabeza/) (que indica como referencia/bibliografía el Diccionario de dichos y frases hechas, de Alberto Buitrago) el origen está en un referencia al Cid (como sospechaba [vasher85 en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12948/5481))

> Puede que la expresión esté ligada a Rodrigo Díaz de Vivar, el Cid. Seguramente fue acuñada durante la batalla de Cuarte (1094)

El Cid decidió tender una emboscada al enemigo almorávide, para lo cual, durante una noche de niebla este

> Ordenó que se liaran los mantos a la cabeza como si fueran turbantes y atacaran sin mirar atrás. Finalmente, la estratagema consiguió confundir al enemigo y las tropas del Cid ganaron la batalla, aunque las bajas fueron muy numerosas.

El artículo menciona otro posible origen

> Otro posible origen se refiere a las batallas medievales, cuando los soldados que iban a asaltar un castillo usaban unos ropajes (las “mantas”) para protegerse la cabeza y la espalda de las piedras, flechas o aceite caliente que les lanzaban los defensores. Como el invento no era demasiado efectivo, quedó la expresión “liarse la manta a la cabeza” como sinónimo de un acto arriesgado que no se ha pensado bien.

Viendo ambas referencias queda más claro que la expresión es "liarse" la manta (para que parezca un turbante o para que quede bien sujeta a la cabeza) y no "echarse" aunque es entendible que la gente la use así, ya que al significar

> Actuar decidida y precipitadamente, de modo irreflexivo (sin tener en cuenta los posibles peligros, ni la opinión ajena).

es normal que la gente piense que simplemente te pones (echas) la manta a la cabeza, lo que te impide ver y oír bien.

Answer (score 1):

El origen de *liarse la manta a la cabeza*, procede de la antigua Grecia de la escuela filosófica estoica de *El Pórtico*, nombre dado porque su fundador enseñaba en un pórtico de Atenas.

En la novela de Petronio, El Satiricón, hay una mención:

> Escuchad mi opinión: El pórtico me sugiere esta solución desesperada:
> Liémonos el vestido a la cabeza y sumerjámonos en el abismo.

Comment: Buenas, Julio, bienvenido al sitio. He editado un poco tu entrada. Las mayúsculas suelen usarse para indicar que ESTÁS GRITANDO. No son necesarias. Tu aporte me parece interesante pero solo he encontrado esa frase en el Satiricón asociada a la traducción de Gredos https://denmeunpapelillo.net/el-satiricon-petronio/ En otras traducciones no aparece. ¿En qué capítulo se encuentra ese fragmento?

Answer (score 0):

Solo añadir a la excelente respuesta de Diego que puede ser que liarse la manta a la cabeza quiera decir convertirse al Islam, y huir a la Morería para escapar de la justicia. Lei una vez esta explicacion y estoy tratando de encontrar la fuente.

Comment: Caramba, interesante hipótesis. Por favor si encuentras tal fuente, dale a [edit] para incorporarla a la respuesta. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La manta ,que uno llevaba siempre consigo si eraplebeyo y que tenía múltiples usos, solía ser parda.Posiblemrnte  esta en el origen de la frase ".liar la parda,o sea,la manta, que quiere decir armar un barullo o confusión,entrar en una pelea,por ejemplo.Ls manta se lía para prepararse para una acción violenta o empresa difícil
Como protección y para no ser estorbado por ella. Liarse la manta a la cabeza sería la protección máxima  en un peligro físico. No hace falta convertirse  al Islam .