# ¿Cuál es el origen de "irse la olla" o "irse la pinza"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia

En España con frecuencia se dice *"se te va la olla"* o *"se te va la pinza"* para indicar que estás actuando de un modo algo irracional. Para mí, también tiene un componente divertido, por lo que es más suave que decir *"estás loco"*.

En [¿De dónde viene “se te va la pinza”?](http://www.sansuavizante.es/de-donde-viene-se-te-va-la-pinza/) dice que:

> Y hasta la Real Academia de la Lengua Española (RAE) me dio otra
>   visión de su origen: “no hemos encontrado ninguna explicación relativa
>   a una anécdota concreta para esta expresión, propia del español
>   peninsular moderno y perteneciente al registro coloquial e informal.
>   Puede entenderse como metafórica, en el sentido de que las pinzas
>   sirven para hacer las conexiones necesarias para que algo funcione, de
>   modo que al irse la pinza se pierde la conexión y el sujeto hace
>   locuras o se comporta de forma anómala”.

Esta incertidumbre respecto al origen de la expresión "irse la pinza" me hace preguntar: ¿se conoce alguna otra explicación histórica de esta expresión? ¿es realmente el origen de "irse la olla" el que menciona el artículo arriba mencionado?

Y además: se usa en España, pero ¿también en Latinoamérica?

Comment: Te puedo asegurar que por lo menos en México no se usa ninguna de las dos expresiones que mencionas y estoy casi convencido de que es una expresión Española tanto en origen como en ámbito de uso.

Comment: En México quizá no se utiliza ninguna de las dos que mencionas, en parte porque, como bien mencionas, la riqueza de la lengua permite que existan expresiones equivalentes y muchas veces muy arraigadas que no permiten ser sustituidas. En México, el equivalente de esas frases sería: ¨se le botó la canica¨. Igualmente desconozco su origen, pero el significado es el mismo.

Comment: Se utiliza bastante en España, sobre todo para indicar que estás loco, o dices tonterías, etc. La verdad, no sé de donde viene ni cuando aprendí la expresión. También se dice "estás follado de la cabeza", pero claro... eso tampoco se lo puedes decir a todo el mundo debido a la connotación más peyorativa.

Comment: Interesante artículo del origen de la expresión! Creo que se usa solamente en España y "se te va la pinza" debe ser una adaptación más reciente, al igual que "se te va la flapa" que alguna vez también he oído.
La lengua es un ser vivo que crece y evoluciona y expresiones como estas con los años irán cambiando.

Comment: En España se usan olla y perola como sinónimos de cabeza (probablemente por el parecido de forma y porque es donde se "cocinan" las ideas). Irse la olla sería por tanto irse la cabeza. Si fue primero la expresión "irse la olla" o usar olla como sinónimo... lo desconozco.

Comment: @fedorqui lo que vengo a decir es que dudo que esa sea la etimología y la olla es, simplemente, una metáfora de la cabeza. Sólo tienes que buscar "Jean-Luc Sagnol" en Google para encontrar que las únicas referencias son a la página que enlazas (y ella misma que, a su vez, carece de referencias).

Comment: @kaoD tienes toda la razón. Hice la misma búsqueda, así como algunas en francés, y nada resultó de ellas. En consecuencia, edito mi pregunta para consultar también si esta historia es correcta o, según cómo, saber cuál es la correcta. ¡Gracias!

Comment: *Emitologías* es una página de humor y las etimologías que presenta son inventadas. Hay quien les critica porque esto no queda del todo claro, aunque ellos alegan que el propio nombre de la página, que es un juego de palabras con *mito*, ya indica que son falsas.

Comment: Bueno, lo era; veo que ya la han cerrado.

Comment: @Gorpik no tenía ni idea de ello y me siento mal por haber caído de una forma tan aparatosa. Elimino la referencia. Gracias por la nota... y voy a buscar si tengo alguna otra pregunta / respuesta usando esta antigua "fuente".

Comment: Ya ves por qué les criticaban :) Al parecer, a sus creadores les hacía mucha gracia que tanta gente se creyera lo que decían.

Comment: @Gorpik confirmado, hay más contenido en este sitio que usa referencias a esa página: [4 ahora mismo](http://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/505048/emitologias-com). Y de hecho... casi todo es mío: [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión “liarse la manta a la cabeza”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12930/1674) y [¿Por qué los valientes tienen “los huevos cuadrados”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15279/1674)

Comment: Habrá que avisar

Comment: @Gorpik revisadas todas eliminando referencias. Esta gente debió cerrar la página al no poder contener tantas carcajadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice @kaod, significa  "írsele a uno la cabeza por algo", queriendo decir que alguien está actuando sin sentido común o coherencia. Siendo una frase coloquial, será difícil encontrar una definición ofical más que en sitios populares.

ejemplos:

- [Respuesta de opiniones personales en Yahoo:](https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101223143242AAR5AWL)  "Se te va la olla = Pierdes la cabeza / Pierdes el juicio / Haces locuras / Reaccionas irracionalmente"
- "Se te va la olla": Frase utilizada por un [restaurante español para nombrar el establecimiento.](https://www.laneveraroja.com/restaurant/n9oc/se-te-va-la-olla-juan-florez-san-pablo)

Quizás esta cita de una [revista filosófica](https://www.um.es/tonosdigital/znum17/secciones/estudios-9-cabeza.htm) es suficientemente oficial:

> Así, pues, a pesar de que la voz española cabeza procede del latín
>   caput, otras lenguas romances como el francés y el italiano derivan su
>   equivalente de cabeza de la voz latina testa (e.j. francés tête,
>   italiano testa), que significa olla. Huellas de esta transferencia
>   metafórica permanecen en el español en la acepción de olla como
>   cabeza, tan frecuente en expresiones como estar mal de la olla o se le
>   va la olla y más explícitamente en el cultismo testa y su derivado
>   testarudo (Mortara, 1980, p. 167)

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Nótese que es recomendable copiar las partes relevantes de los enlaces que das; de lo contrario, si dejan de funcionar pasarán a no ser útiles.

Comment: Yo quitaría el enlace al restaurante, que parece _spam_ y el de yahoo, que no aporta nada.

Comment: La única referencia valiosa la veo en el enlace último, especialmente: «Así, pues, a pesar de que la voz española cabeza procede del latín _caput_, otras lenguas romances como el francés y el italiano derivan su equivalente de cabeza de la voz latina _testa_ (ej. francés _tête_, italiano _testa_), que significa olla.(...) (Mortara, 1980, p. 167)». Desmiente a las claras la etimología de la anécdota del cocinero.

Comment: Respuesta actualizada con citas de los enlaces. El enlace del restaurante es un ejemplo de uso en la vida real, demostrando que es una frase conocida en España. El de yahoo también muestra que la respuesta a conceptos coloquiales o del lunfardo proviene de la gente que la utiliza.

Comment: Caramba, no había visto tu actualización. Ahora tiene mucho sentido la referencia a la revista filosófica con su símil de olla y cabeza. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

En Latin la cabeza se denomina testa, que en su origen significaba un recipiente de barro cocido, igual que una olla, de donde deriva también la palabra española tiesto. De modo que llamar a la cabeza olla o tiesto tiene un origen muy antiguo.
De ahí la expresión "irse la olla" por "irse la cabeza".

Answer (score 0):

En Francia, se dice de manera dulce "Il a perdu la tête" literalmente "ha perdido la cabeza" y la cabeza es como una olla donde se cocina muchas cosas ! Pero también se dice - manera mas violenta y familiar- "Il a pété les plombs", "ha cruzado los cables (o los plomos), eso me haciendo pensar a la definición de la Real Academia : *...de modo que al irse la pinza se pierde la conexión y el sujeto hace locuras o se comporta de forma anómala”.*
"Pété" en francès es la misma palabra que hacer un pedo. Y también se puede imaginar que el culo es también una olla...