# ¿Podría un hispanohablante actual entenderse bien con uno del pasado?

Tags: historia, españa

Supongo que, al igual que yo, mucha gente en este foro habrá visto algún capítulo de *El Ministerio del Tiempo*. En esta serie viajan al pasado dentro de España, hasta tiempos tan remotos como el siglo XIII. Sin embargo, la forma en que se representa el español hablado en aquellas fechas varía del nuestro simplemente en la elección de palabras para expresar algunos conceptos: la gramática se mantiene intacta, y los viajeros del tiempo pueden comunicarse con personas de dichos siglos sin levantar la más mínima sospecha.

Mas basta con leer una [primera edición del Quijote](http://quijote.bne.es/libro.html) para ver que las formas de construir las frases ya difieren notablemente de las de hoy, y que algunas construcciones pueden ser difíciles de entender para un hablante actual.

Así pues, y aun a riesgo de generar un debate que no tenga respuesta, pongamos como bases lo siguiente:

1. El viajero del tiempo sabe qué palabras usar en cada época (ejemplo, "vuestra merced" en lugar de "usted").
2. El viajero del tiempo no va a usar tiempos verbales extremadamente complejos (como el futuro de subjuntivo) ni va a entrar en conversaciones demasiado temáticas, sólo charla de la calle.
3. El viajero del tiempo no tiene amplios conocimientos de la cultura o contextos históricos del momento al que viaja, sólo ideas generales.
4. La diferencia temporal de acentos se puede explicar de la misma forma que la diferencia espacial (diciendo que eres de otro sitio), por lo que no importan.
5. Se supone un periodo de adaptación de uno o dos días para que el viajero del tiempo se adapte a las peculiaridades de la época.

¿Hasta qué año podríamos irnos atrás en el tiempo y llegar a entendernos sin demasiados problemas con los *nativos* de la época? No importaría el hecho de que nos mirasen raro por las diferencias, no se trata de hacerse pasar por nativo. ¿El español de la calle en el siglo XVI (por poner) era realmente tan parecido al nuestro?

Comment: En este sitio nos entendemos perfectamente con [guifa](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/4182/guifa), cuyo español es bastante pretérito ;-)

Comment: *Ẽtẽderſe, Ẽtẽderſe auié,* :-)  aunque creo que solo por el acento sería difícil pasar mucho más de los cien años (suponiendo que supiésemos cuándo usar los varios tratamientos de 2.ª persona — ¿te imaginas usar el de *él*?  Afortunadamente, aquel no duró mucho). Hay que tener en cuenta que lo que se escribía no era lo que se decía. Además, antes del siglo XIII tenemos pocos documentos en lo que de verdad podríamos llamar castellano (como algo distinto del leonés o aragonés, etc), pero el libro de 1492 con que trabajo ahora, dirigido al hombre común, se entiende bastante bien hoy en día.

Comment: @guifa Es cierto, lo que se escribía y lo que se decía no era lo mismo, y entiendo que es complicado saber cómo se hablaba en la calle en épocas remotas, pero hago la pregunta ya por curiosidad. Voy a actualizar las bases suponiendo que los acentos no importan, porque se pueden explicar diciendo que vienes de lejos.

Comment: El título de esta pregunta no corresponde con el párrafo final. Una cosa es entenderse y otra hacerse pasar por un "nativo" del periodo en cuestión. No queda claro si la pregunta es a) podríamos entendernos b) podríamos hacernos pasar por o c) cómo de lejos podemos ir en el tiempo para XYZ?

Comment: @guifa sería interesante valorar hasta qué punto tener una academia de la lengua es un ingrediente importante en esta fórmula: en el caso del catalán, es muy complicado entender textos que tienen apenas 100 años, cuando aún no se había normalizado la lengua (se estaba haciendo en esos momentos).

Comment: @Diego tienes razón, [se me fue un poco la olla](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13638/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-irse-la-olla-o-irse-la-pinza) en la última parte. Voy a cambiarla para que refleje más la cuestión principal, y de paso hacer la pregunta un poco menos subjetiva.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Parece ser que el texto más antiguo conocido en lengua castellana son las [Glosas emilianenses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glosas_Emilianenses), una serie de anotaciones de los siglos X y XI escritas en castellano y vasco al margen de un texto en latín. Aquí hay un fragmento, cortesía de [Wikisource](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Glosas_Emilianenses):

[image: Versión original: Con o aiutorio de nuestro dueno Christo dueno / salbatore, qual dueno / get ena honore et qual / duenno tienet ela / mandatione con o / patre con o spiritu sancto / en os sieculos de lo siecu / los. Facanos Deus Omnipotes / tal serbitio fere ke / denante ela sua face / gaudioso segamus. Amen. // Versión actual: Con la ayuda de nuestro Señor Don Cristo Don / Salvador, Señor que está en el honor y / Señor que tiene el / mandato con el / Padre con el Espíritu Santo / en los siglos de los siglos. / Háganos Dios omnipotente / hacer tal servicio que / delante de su faz / gozosos seamos. Amén]

Suponiendo que la persona con la que te encuentres hable un registro similar al de nuestro monje, con un poco de esfuerzo y tras acostumbrarse a sus particularidades habría que ver si la comunicación es posible. También ayuda que se conozcan otros idiomas romances peninsulares como el portugués, gallego, catalán o asturiano, o extrapeninsulares como el italiano o rumano, para rellenar los huecos que el castellano no cubra.

Ahora, hay algunas controversias acerca de si las Glosas emilianenses fueron realmente escritas en castellano o algún dialecto hispánico. Aquí hay un texto que es más claramente castellano, aunque dos siglos posterior:

> 543. Sj alguna christiana fiziere fornjçio con judio o con moro o con omne de otra ley, seyendo fallados en el fecho, o si les fuere sabido por pesquisa derecha, amos ssean quemados.
> 544. Sj alguno que fuere sieruo de otro casare con la mugier daquel cuyo sieruo fue, amos mueran por ello, tan bien ella commo el.
> 545. Sj alguna mugier prennada, por qual culpa quier que ffaga fuere judgada amuerte o a pena del cuerpo, non ssea justiçiada njn aya pena ninguna en su [f. 92v] cuerpo fasta que sea parida. Mas si debda alguna deuiere & non ouier de que la pagar, rrecabdenla por prision o por otra guisa, sin pena de su cuerpo, fasta que pague la debda.
>
> Anónimo (c 1196). *Fuero de Soria.*

Este se entiende un poco mejor, pero habría que ver si la pronunciación permitiría la comprensión. Yo entiendo el portugués escrito, pero no el portugués hablado; y algo similar me ocurre con el francés. Que entienda el contenido del texto no significa necesariamente que sea capaz de mantener una conversación hablada en el castellano de la misma época.

Veamos algunos otros textos:

> "Las partidas deuen prometer la una a la otra la pena que es en el conpromisso puesta, et si aqueilla pena fuere prometida al árbitro, tenido es el árbitro, et ante la pena dada, et depués, a cada una de las partidas contra la otra, de leixar el pleito quoando quiere que aqueilla partida lo demandare, (17) sobre esto ni aqueill árbitro aurá algo d'aqueilla pena, ante, si demandare la pena o partida d'aqueilla pena d'aqueilla partida que non quiere obedir en iuditio ho fuera de iuditio, deue dar todo aqueillo que demandare a la partida que quiere obedir."
>
> Anónimo (c 1250). *Vidal Mayor.*
>
> "Sigujent mjentre es a dezir de los sortores. Mando encara que, si algún sortor de las cosas que le fueren dadas a obrar cameará o furtará et prouado'l fuere, péchelo asín como ladrón; si non, jure solo, si le oujere sospecha, et sea credido. Que algunos d'ellos suelen a las deuegadas alguna cosa de los pannyos furtar o de las pielles o de la orla. Mas si el sennor de la obra o de las uesteduras prouar non lo pudiere et el dannyo fuere de V sueldos asuso, el sortor sáluese así como de furto, segunt razón del dannyo; de V sueldos ayuso, así como es dicho, jure solo."
>
> Anónimo (c 1300). *Fuero de Teruel.*
>
> "Estando este Çid Ruy Díaz en la su çibdad de Valençia, el grand soldán de Persia, porque oyera dezir de las grandes vondades d'él en el fecho de las armas qu'el Çid fazía e cómo nunca fuera vençido de moros ni de cristianos e cómo ganara la çibdad de Valençia e otros muchos castillos, ovo sabor de ser su amigo e enbió a él un cavallero mucho onrado, que era su pariente, con muchos nobles dones, con sus cartas de muchas palabras amigables e de grande amor. E como el Çid sopo su venida, saliólo a reçebir con toda su gente noblemente vestidos, e sus cavallos e armas con sus pajes a par de sí, que eran más de mil D cavalleros, a una legua de Valençia, que encontraron aquel moro con su noble conpañía."
>
> García de Salazar, Lope (1471 - 1476). *Istoria de las bienandanzas e fortunas.*
>
> "Si dizes que para acordarte de Dios no has menester ymagines, es verdad, y no te las dan para esso, sino para que te mueba a effectos la representazion de la deydad que reuerenziamos y del Señor que amamos sobre todo bien; como los enamorados, que el retrato de su dama no le trahen para acordarse de ella, pues ya presume memoria el acordarse que le trae para sacarle: trahelo sòlo para deleytarse con la parte que se le conçede del bien ausente. Dizes tanbien que Cristo pagò por todos, y que no ay sino viuir como quisieremos, porque el que me hizo a mì sin mì, me saluarà a mì sin mì. Bien que me hizo sin mì, pero hecho, siente que se destruya su hobra, manche su pintura y vorre su ymagen."
>
> Quevedo y Villegas, Francisco de (1608). *Sueño del Infierno.*

La facilidad para comprender el texto aumenta, evidentemente, según las fechas se van acercando a la actual. Yo personalmente considero que el castellano del siglo XVIII, tomando solo los documentos escritos, es prácticamente indistinguible del español actual, o no se distingue del mismo más que, por ejemplo, algún dialecto hispanoamericano. Hasta entonces, la evolución del castellano se ha dado en un proceso gradual, por lo que a partir de cuándo se empieza a comprender es difícil de decir, y (pura especulación) tendría que ser en algún momento entre el siglo X y el XV.

---

Existe, en realidad, un texto aún más antiguo al de las Glosas: los [Cartularios de Valpuesta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartularios_de_Valpuesta), del siglo IX. He aquí un fragmento del año 844 con su traducción (más ejemplos en el enlace):

> "...in loco que uocitant Elzeto cum fueros de totas nostras absque aliquis uis causa, id est, de illa costegera de Valle Conposita usque ad illa uinea de Ual Sorazanes et deinde ad illo plano de Elzeto et ad Sancta Maria de Uallelio usque ad illa senra de Pobalias (...), posuimus inter nos fuero que nos fratres poniamus custodiero de Sancta Maria de Valle Conpossita..."
>
> "...en el lugar que llaman Elicedo con fueros de todas las nuestras excepto alguna causa de fuerza, esto es, de la costera de Valpuesta hasta la viña de Val Sorazanes y de allí al llano de Elicedo y a Santa María de Vallejo hasta la sierra de Pobalias (...), hemos puesto entre nosotros fuero que nosotros hermanos pongamos guardián de Santa María de Valpuesta..."

El enlace explica algunos cambios, tanto gráficos y fonéticos (f > h, x > ç, u > o, etc.) como sintácticos (se abandonan los casos latinos, se favorece la estructura sujeto-verbo-complementos, plural con "s", etc.), que alejan al texto del latín y lo acercan al castellano. Basándose en los textos presentados, es un tanto optimista pensar que pueda haber comunicación entre un hispanoparlante del siglo IX y uno moderno. Es igualmente difícil en el año 1000 (*Glosas emilianas*), y parece que se vuelve algo más sencillo hacia el 1200 (*Fuero de Soria*). Si tuviera que aventurar un número, apostaría por el siglo XIII.

<sub>NOTA: Todos los textos se han extraído del CORDE, un corpus de textos en castellano digitalizados, con los posibles errores de digitalización de todo OCR.</sub>

Comment: Te doy +1 porque no te puedo dar +10. Es muy curioso cómo en las glosas se ven rasgos del castellano actual, pero aún así son muy difíciles de entender. Fantásticos los ejemplos en los que se va viendo la evolución del idioma. Y muy acertada la idea de que una cosa es entender el lenguaje escrito y otra el lenguaje hablado. Sería apasionante poder tener registros de cómo se hablaba el castellano en aquel entonces, una lástima que no pueda ser así.

Comment: Efectivamente, y también está la cuestión del registro. Los documentos más antiguos que se tienen están escritos en un registro formal, diferente del que hablaba la gente de calle.

Comment: Por cierto, parece que hay unas obras más antiguas a las Glosas, los [Cartularios de Valpuesta](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartularios_de_Valpuesta), aunque parecen más latín teñido de castellano que castellano propiamente dicho: «...in loco que uocitant Elzeto cum fueros de totas nostras absque aliquis uis causa, id est, de illa costegera de Valle Conposita usque ad illa uinea de Ual Sorazanes et deinde ad illo plano de Elzeto..." (844) En el siglo XI parece haber habido un cambio determinante en el castellano, a lo mejor alguien que sepa más de historia pueda explicarlo con más detalle.

Comment: Bueno, pero seguramente una cosa es entender el extracto de arriba cuando hay tiempo para escrutarlo, y otra cosa es entenderlo cuando lo dice un monje al ritmo del habla normal y con un acento extraño.

Answer (score 9):

Mi opinión. (Esto probablemente debería ir en los comentarios pero lo pongo aquí porque es extenso).

Hace un tiempo vi una comedia puertorriqueña muy mala por Netflix y me vi obligado a activar los subtítulos. Yo soy chileno y la verdad no estaba entendiendo nada. Me imagino que algunos vecinos (Miami, República Dominicana, tal vez Colombia) entenderán fácilmente el español coloquial de Puerto Rico, pero a mí se me hace difícil. Sin embargo entiendo a las mil maravillas a los argentinos, que son tan "raros" que incluso conjugan distinto al resto de los hispanohablantes.

A qué voy. El tiempo es sólo uno de los factores de variación de español. Las variaciones formal/informal y culto/inculto pueden ser enormes. La gracia está en que el idioma español es *un solo sistema*. Si nos exponemos a una variedad extraña (p.ej. al español del siglo XV) no necesitamos "aprender" esa variedad, sino que solo necesitamos "acostumbrarnos".

Entonces, para responder a tu pregunta:

- El español antiguo es tan distinto para mí como lo podría ser cualquier dialecto español con el que no tengo contacto, por poner mi caso, la variedad de Filipinas, o la variedad informal inculta de Nicaragua.
- Cuando me encuentre con un hablante del español del siglo XIII (o con el filipino del siglo XXI) necesitaremos un tiempo breve para poder comunicarnos perfectamente. Y con breve me refiero a unas pocas horas. La fonética es casi instantánea, es como aprender a leer una nueva tipografía. El vocabulario es irrelevante, es cosa de preguntar qué quiere decir tal palabra. Lo más difícil es la gramática, pero la gramática *es* el español y está inscrita en nuestra mente desde los 3 años de edad.
- Si busco hacia atrás en el tiempo y llego a un punto en el que no entiendo una jota, eso no es español, es latín.

Comment: Fantástico análisis. PD: ¿qué es la pinta de los argentinos?

Comment: @fedorqui Lo edité. "A su pinta" es un chilenismo, significa que hacen las cosas distinto a lo normal, a lo reglamentario o a lo que piensen los demás.

Comment: Aaah, esto lo llamaríamos "a su bola" en España. Claro ejemplo de tu respuesta: en pocos minutos nos entendemos.

Comment: Estupenda y constructiva respuesta, ¡muchas gracias! ¿Podríamos entonces afinar algún periodo de tiempo en el cual el castellano pasa a parecerse más a nuestro idioma que al latín? ¿O fue un cambio demasiado lento como para restringirlo a, digamos, un siglo? Añado a las premisas la de suponer un periodo de adaptación.

Answer (score 4):

Tengo que decir que considero la pregunta ambigua, pero no creo que merezca puntos negativos por ello o marcarla en la forma en que es usual en este lugar. Al contrario, me parece una pregunta interesante precisamente por eso.

Si tengo que responderla tal como está expresada, tengo que decir que sí, pero por la siguiente razón: *ser hispanohablante, por definición, implica hablar español y, si dos personas hablan el mismo idioma, han de entenderse, puesto que, si no, **no hablarían el mismo idioma***.

Después de decir esta perogrullada uno se da cuenta de que el meollo del asunto está en qué se quiere decir con *español* y qué con *entender*, que a simple vista parece de lo más sencillo. Sin embargo veremos que la cosa se puede complicar bastante.

Empecemos planteándonos esta pregunta: ¿Pueden un italiano y un español del presente entenderse (asumiendo que cada uno solo conoce su idioma)? ¿Y un español y un portugués? ¿Y si habla uno en español y el otro en bable? Por experiencia propia o por testimonios tendremos que decir que sí. Al menos, bastante. Lo suficiente para ser funcional en la mayoría de los casos.

*Entender* es un verbo que puede tener un significado claro cuando se aplica a una afirmación concreta. ¿Y si te das cuenta de que algo se te escapa? No puedes decir que no te has enterado de nada ni que lo has entendido del todo. ¿Qué pasa cuando se aplica a dos si una se entiende y la otra no? En la comunicación entre dos personas hay miles de actos comunicativos, de los cuales algunos se entienden completamente, otros en mayor o menor parte y otros nada en absoluto.

También hay que tener en cuenta que el idioma no es ni mucho menos el único elemento que influye. Otro que tiene un peso **enorme** es la cultura: los objetos, situaciones, costumbres, conocimiento (real o aceptado como tal), puntos ciegos, roles, ideales, intereses, perspectivas, prejuicios, tabúes, experiencias espirituales... que conforman el ideario de una sociedad.

Las lenguas son seres escurridizos y las distinciones claras entre ellas a veces están forzadas y simplificadas para comodidad de los lingüistas. De esta cómoda arbitrariedad que se proporcionan los lingüistas se queja varias veces William C. Stokoe en su libro "Language in Hand. Why Sign Came Before Speech". Por ejemplo, y al hilo de la mutua inteligibilidad entre hablantes del mismo idioma:

> Some facts about spoken languages are clear: (a) there are numerous
>   spoken languages in the world today; (b) there were spoken languages
>   in the relatively recent past; and (c) the differences among spoken
>   languages are many. An exact count even of current spoken languages
>   cannot be made, however, because such a count would vary according to
>   whether some systems are considered to be different languages or
>   dialects of the same language.This distinction requires drawing an
>   arbitrary line between a language and a dialect.
>
> As can be discovered readily in urban America, speakers of some
>   varieties of English, a world language, have more or less difficulty
>   understanding speakers of their own language when they come from
>   different regions and social strata. The way speakers put sentences
>   together and the variations in their sentence melody and rhythm create
>   as much difficulty in mutual intelligibility as the way they pronounce
>   the vowels and consonants.

Los problemas que surgen al intentar responder esta pregunta son similares a los que aparecen cuando se habla de especies en Biología. ¿Qué es una especie? Para aquellos que quieran aprender al respecto, les aconsejo que lean ["El cuento de la salamandra"](https://books.google.es/books?id=ooaSZRE7wRAC&pg=PA411&lpg=PA411&dq=el+cuento+del+antepasado+gaviotas+polares&source=bl&ots=qNnkBF1lyK&sig=lKcMYtfqVZAx4CR1BsjCfODrSHY&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjElP7FqMDNAhVF8RQKHToADL4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) ([original en inglés](https://books.google.es/books?id=Scxg1Pu3dOsC&pg=PT249&lpg=PT249&dq=tale+ancestor+salamander&source=bl&ots=A-Dvaz5nn7&sig=IJUEBKyyUKA9cDVLiX4cDL6yPhY&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid6LexrMDNAhVBkx4KHYZlDcsQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)), del libro "El cuento del antepasado" de Richard Dawkins. En él, el autor hace una exposición de lo que considera "la tiranía de la mente discontinua". Hablar del español de ahora y del de hace unos siglos y si sus hablantes se entenderían es similar al problema de decidir, en algunos casos, si dos animales son de la misma o distinta especie (como ocurre con las salamandras y las gaviotas del texto); o, más aún, al caso del Homo Sapiens y sus antepasados (del que también habla): ¿en qué momento dejaron de ser miembros de la misma especie?

Exigir unos límites claros puede ser imprescindible en la vida. ¿En qué momento un niño deja de ser hombre? ¿A los 18 o 21? Esta es una frontera que hay que definir, en parte, de forma arbitraria por cuestiones principalmente legales, porque hay actos que implican una responsabilidad ante los demás. Sin embargo, todos sabemos que es una raya ficticia y que el 18º cumpleaños no transforma la mente de un niño en la de un hombre.

En otros casos, como en Lingüística o Biología, son más bien una comodidad que funciona en la mayoría de los casos pero que hemos de tener presente que no es más que eso: un truco de escamoteo que queda bien. Ahora lo ves, ahora no lo ves. No hay que tomárselo muy en serio.

**Resumiendo**:

Respondiendo sin sutileza, sí. Entrando en más profundidad, he intentado explicar por qué creo que la pregunta es ambigua, pero que encuentro lícito que se haga y que merece una respuesta que espero que sirva para hacernos más cuidadosos a la hora de tomar ciertas decisiones. No esta, que al fin es intrascendente, pero sí otras que, como dice Dawkins, pueden ser "fuente de verdadero sufrimiento, de sufrimiento humano".

Terminaré con [una frase que leí una vez](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/02/07/two-classes/) y que merecería un [premio Ig Nobel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premio_Ig_Nobel), porque primero hace reír y luego hace pensar:

> Solo hay dos tipos de personas: las que dividen a las personas en dos
>   tipos y las que no.

Comment: Cuando hice la pregunta era consciente de que iba a ser algo complicado de responder, o que sólo se podría responder con tentativas. Pero aun así no considero la pregunta como perteneciente únicamente al ámbito de la opinión, ya que se pueden aportar pruebas que apoyen las teorías de cada uno. La respuesta de Yay, de hecho, es un ejemplo de ello, y ha ido más allá de lo que yo esperaba. Te agradezco enormemente tu análisis sobre la validez de la pregunta y me alegra que tu conclusión sea a favor de la misma.

Comment: Sí, la respuesta de Yay es [para quitarse el sombrero](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17175/kudos-en-espa%C3%B1ol) y el valor que tiene la pregunta que haces es, precisamente, que no tiene una respuesta clara y obliga a justificar las explicaciones que se den. Y los que las leemos aprendemos cosas interesantes.

Answer (score 1):

Es una pregunta imposible de responder si hablas de acento, palabras, e incluso conocimiento cultural. Mi humilde opinión: sin viajar en el tiempo, solo cruzando de un lado a otro dentro de un país, entre dos ciudades cercanas, o incluso entre dos barrios dentro de una misma ciudad, vas a encontrar diferencias en todos esos aspectos. Ni qué decir si agregas un viaje en el tiempo.

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión, permíteme por favor defender la mía. [Aquí](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:S3HT-6QM7-N35) tienes (abajo a la derecha) la partida de nacimiento de la persona que dio origen a mi apellido Alejo. Dejando aparte la diferencia de las grafías, se entiende perfectamente, y es de mediados del siglo XVII. Guifa trata con libros del siglo XV que también se entienden, y @Rodrigo ya ha medio respondido a la pregunta. Sólo queda saber en qué periodo en castellano se parecía más al latín que al castellano.

Comment: Igual la pregunta está formulada un poco en el ámbito de la ciencia ficción, pero si la quieres ver así, se trata de averiguar en qué periodo histórico empieza el castellano a parecerse realmente a nuestro idioma actual más que al latín.

Comment: Era que preguntes así, jaja. Dale, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la respuesta ya ha sido asignada, quisiera proponer otro enfoque que puede terminar en el foro de Mathematics, pero creo que vale la pena.
Partamos de una teoría. 1) una lista de palabras van desapareciendo de un idioma de una forma [exponencial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crecimiento_exponencial#Decrecimiento_exponencial), de la siguiente forma:

> N(t) = N<sub>0</sub>e<sup>-λt</sup>

*En cristiano*, N(t) son las palabras que se usan hoy, N<sub>0</sub> es el número de palabras que se quieren conocer, para nuestro caso, las palabras del hablante del pasado. e = 2,71828182845... ([Valor de e](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_e)), t viene en milenios (cuantos milenios han pasado en el tiempo, si hablas de alguien de 1617 t = 0,4) y (aquí se pone fea la fórmula) si no me falla la memoria (hace rato no manejo exponenciales) λ es el porcentaje de palabras que cambian cada milenio.
(véase Calculo con Geometría analítica de Edwards & Penney, capítulo 7 sección 5)

Hasta ahí todo suena *bello e incomprensible...* pero nuestro problema surge a la hora de llenar la formula: ¿Cuántas palabras usa el hispanohablante del pasado (N<sub>0</sub>)? Alguna vez leí que personas con poca preparación le basta con 900 palabras en el día a día (no tengo la fuente, pero no me convence), o un ejemplo que me convence más lo vemos [acá](https://www.defensacentral.com/ustedpregunta/categoria/gramatica/cual-es-el-minimo-de-palabras-necesarias-para-comunicarse-en-una-lengua/). Y al haber establecido las palabras de nuestro huésped del pasado, lo más bonito de todo... ¿Cuál es el valor de λ en español? y en ese punto se enreda esta respuesta. En un ejercicio del libro anteriormente citado, dan como valor del inglés λ=0.77 (es decir que  cada milenio cambian 77% de vocablos) pero google academics no me ayuda mucho con el tema en español. No sé si en la RAE se conozca el valor o se tenga un aprox. pero si aplicas la fórmula con los valores válidos, se tendría un valor de cuantos vocablos se seguirían usando hoy día. (valga aclarar que hay términos que aunque en desuso, son comprensibles)

Comment: Es un enfoque interesante, aunque falten datos para llegar a una respuesta. De todos modos, en castellano no estoy seguro de que esa fórmula nos sirva, porque considero que el valor de λ es variable en el tiempo. En concreto, creo que la evolución del lenguaje se ha ralentizado desde la normalización de principios del siglo XVIII. Por eso el español del siglo XVI es mucho más parecido al actual que al del siglo XI. Esto no ha ocurrido en inglés.

Comment: @Gorpik, de todas formas uno que otro cambio gramático ha habido y sin ir muy lejos, nunca faltan las palabras de jerga que pueden durar desde meses hasta unas pocas décadas en una región y no alcanzan a considerarse en la academia... pero ya eso se debate en las otras respuestas