# ¿"Kudos" en español?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Estaba leyendo [una respuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/1983854) del Community Manager de Stack Exchange, [Shog9](http://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) cuando me fijé en la última parte:

> **Kudos** to [Michael Stum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum) for implementing this change - also, please join me in welcoming him to the core development team!

Yo lo traduciría como

> Desde aquí, **mis agradecimientos** a...

O incluso de una forma más directa, como sugiere [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=kudos):

> **Gloria** a...

¿Qué os parece a vosotros? ¿Cuál podría ser una buena forma de usar este término en castellano?

Comment: En español creo que lo habitual es, simplemente, escribir *Gracias a...* En este caso: *Gracias a Michael Sturm por implementar este cambio [...]*

Comment: @Gorpik uhms, curioso. Leyendo [su origen](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kudos) en dictionary.com me daba la sensación de ser algo más "elevado" que _gracias_: _In the 19th century, kudos 1entered English as a singular noun, a transliteration of a Greek singular noun kŷdos meaning “praise or renown.” It was at first used largely in academic circles, but it gained wider currency in the 1920s in journalistic use, particularly in headlines: Playwright receives kudos. Kudos given to track record breakers._

Comment: Entiendo que _kudos_ pueda ser algo más elevado que un simple "gracias", pero decir "gloria a" a mí me suena como a broma. Si quieres enfatizar, ¿qué tal un **"mil gracias"**?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo no me convence. En la referencia de mi anterior comentario se menciona que empezó en círculos académicos; ahora ya no lo es, pero _mil gracias_ me parece demasiado informal para el caso.

Comment: @fedorqui En efecto, *kudos* no es estrictamente equivalente a *thanks*, que se podría haber usado también en esa frase. Pero, en mi opinión, el significado de *kudos* ya no es tan *elevado* porque se ha generalizado demasiado, así que tampoco se va demasiado del que tiene el simple *thanks*. De todos modos, lo que quería decir era que en español lo habitual en esas situaciones es el simple *gracias*, aunque tenemos otras expresiones que, aunque solo sea por ser menos habituales, dan mayor énfasis. *Mi agradecimiento a...*, *Con mi reconocimiento a...*, *Un hurra por...*

Comment: Supongo que lo que subyace aquí es la magnitud del agradecimiento que representa _kudos_. Interesante tu aportación, @Gorpik que enlaza con lo que dijo Carlos -inicialmente un _mil gracias_ sonaría demasiado corriente, pero la popularización del uso hace que en según qué contexto sí sea válido-. ¡Qué interesante es la evolución en el uso de las palabras!

Comment: En este caso, ¿y si nos olvidamos de los formalismos? Pasemos de los discursos preparados y meditados, en los que sí se pueden usar recursos como _mi agradecimiento a_ o _me descubro ante_ (que también valen como respuesta), y vayamos a la espontaneidad. ¿Qué os sale de dentro cuando queréis agradecer algo infinito? ¿Qué decís cuando un simple "gracias" no es suficiente?

Comment: Utilizaría `mis felicitaciones a ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo diría

> Me quito el sombrero ante...

o

> Me descubro ante...

Creo que en español esta frase hecha da reconocimiento y expresa admiración ante un logro como *kudos* en inglés.

Answer (score 3):

En general se refiere a felicitar a una persona por un acto o porque haya recibido una recompensa justa.

Así, se diría:

> Felicitaciones a fulano or tal o cual acto o cosa.

Me baso en una versión española de las definiciones en inglés halladas en el Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary Eleventh Edition página6 93.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta, ASTaylor y bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Answer (score 0):

Para nada es un agradecimiento de ninguna naturaleza, es una expresión de **reconocimiento**.

No tendrías que **agradecerle** a De Niro por su último papel en una película, pero si darle **reconocimiento** y en castellano hay varias formas de hacerlo
Kudos on your last performance Robert!

¡ Bravo,

**Mi reconocimiento**,

Enhorabuena,

Albricias,

Mucho,

Excelente,

Muy bien,

Etc. …

por tu última actuación en xxx película “

Pero no “ Gracias “

¿ vale ?