# Cuál es la mejor traducción para "Spoiler"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

> A **[spoiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_(media))** is an element of a disseminated summary or description of any piece of fiction that reveals any plot elements which threaten to give away important details concerning the turn of events of a dramatic episode.

Es decir, que un *spoiler* es como ya sabemos eso que nos arruina una obra de ficción (película, serie, libro, cómic...) que todavía no hemos visto, oído, leído... Es bastante común ahora encontrarse con la reseña o discusión de, digamos, el más reciente episodio de Juego de Tronos y encontrar *advertencias* o *spoiler alerts* por si todavía no has visto el episodio, leído los libros o lo que sea.

La traducción para `spoil` sería `arruinar` o `echar a perder` (entre otras muchas posibilidades para otros contextos, como "malcriar", "consentir" o "botín (de guerra) ).

Las advertencias "spoiler ahead" se suelen traducir como "spoilers a continuación". El "spoiler alert/warning" no es más que "advertencia: spoilers". No me imagino las traducciones más obvias "Advertencia *arruinadores*" o "*arruinadores* a continuación" sustituyendo a las traducciones anteriores.

¿Existe una traducción "oficial" o aceptada para el anglicismo `spoiler`?

---

Hace poco leía en la prensa los esfuerzos de la Real Academia de la Lengua Española por concienciar a la gente de usar menos anglicismos si hay una opción en castellano para un cierto término ([multiples artículos sobre tal campaña](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rae%20swine%20campa%C3%B1a)).

La verdad es que esta campaña me recordó los esfuerzos de nuestro moderador @fedorqui con [muchas de sus preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui) para encontrar equivalentes en español a anglicismos de uso diario. [Kudos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17175/kudos-en-espa%C3%B1ol) para fedorqui por sus esfuerzos.

De ahí mi motivación a contribuir con esta pregunta, tratando de entender cómo nos libraría la RAE de este anglicismo tan aceptado.

Comment: En ingles 'spolier alert' es un neologismo (segun Google ngrams)

Comment: ¡Gracias por los _kudos_! Lo mismo es un poco _off-topic_ aquí, pero [se] ofrece un bloque de texto para spoiler: `>!`, jeje.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La traducción más adecuada para *spoil* es [destripar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DV96tNu).

> **4.** *tr. coloq.* Interrumpir el relato que está haciendo alguien de algún suceso, chascarrillo, enigma, etc., anticipando el desenlace o la
>   solución.

De ahí al «destripe» va un proceso de derivación normal que, además, [está avalado por la Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/destripe-en-vez-de-spoiler/).

Comment: ["Si usted ya la vio no cuente el final. Si usted aún no la vio..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUoA0vMEUxM). Y, bueno, no quisiera reventar el final de "El asesino misterioso". De acuerdo en que "destripar" es el mejor término y, aunque "destripe" aún no es habitual, creo que es cuestión de usarlo y acabará siéndolo. Solo añadir que en español también existe el término "destripacuentos" para la persona que nos destripa el argumento de algo. Y los hay profesionales.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv Qué grandes Les Luthiers.

Answer (score 4):

Particularmente, mi opción favorita para *spoiler* como verbo es [destripar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17189/12637), como se ha dicho en otra respuesta, pero aún me suena raro (y un poco gore) el sustantivo *destripe*.

Para *spoiler alert*, me gustaría proponer como opción:

> **Secretos** [de la trama] **desvelados** [a continuación].

Creo que queda muy conciso y respeta el espíritu del original.

Answer (score 3):

*Arruinar* o *echar a perder* es lo que más se escucha, especialmente en la televisión doblada.

En Colombia usamos una frase que no sé si es gramaticalmente correcta: Cuando alguien por ejemplo te cuenta el final de la película o hace un comentario sobre el episodio de "Juego de tronos" que aún no has visto, exclamamos:

> ¡¡¡Te me tiraste en la película!!!

Para el *spoiler alert* si no conozco ninguna traducción pero cuando sospechamos que alguien va a hacer el comentario que nos **arruinará** la película, lo detenemos con un enfático **"Cuidado te me tiras la película"**

Comment: Cuando dices "Para el _spoiler alert_ si no conozco ninguna traducción", ¿qué es este _si no_? ¿Lo que diríamos en España "sí que no"?

Comment: Exactamente @fedorqui. Por estos lados casi siempre lo decimos así. Por ejemplo: "Si en esa frase el 'que' es necesario, eso **si no** los sé"

Comment: ¡Interesante! ¿Y usáis un _si_ sin tilde?

Answer (score 3):

También se puede tomar como *aguafiestas*.
Entonces podría interpretarse como *spoilers ahead = aguafiestas adelante*.

Por supuesto que nadie diría *información que revela la trama de un libro o película* en una afirmación del estilo:

> Spoiler alert = alerta de información que revela la trama de la película,

pues, es muy largo, entonces queda bien al poner *aguafiestas adelante*, a saber, que te van a estropear lo que estás a punto de hacer.

Comment: +1, aunque yo cambiaría el _adelante_: me suena forzado. *¿Peligro?*, *¿advertencia?*, *¿aviso?*

Comment: No sé la verdad pero *aguafiestas* no lo usaría en este contexto, me suena demasiado raro. En especial cuando la definición se refiere a una persona...

Answer (score 2):

La RAE en twitter ([#RAEconsultas](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/990982940447436800)) contesta a un usuario:

> "En español puede usarse «destripe» (del verbo «destripar»: 'anticipar el desenlace de una historia a quienes no lo conocen'). No obstante, también esta previsto incorporar al diccionario académico la adaptación gráfica «espóiler».

Comment: ¡Dios mío...! Afortunadamente, aun no han cometido está tropelía.

Answer (score 0):

Un variante de varias propuestas hechas en esta página:

**spoiler alert = *secreto revelado***

Por ejemplo

**Secreto revelado**:

> Demostración de *secreto revelado*