# Translation Golf XVII - "We rule the world"

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Winner: [CarlosAlejo with a translation golfed down to just 86 letters](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22078/13628). Impressive!

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition's proposed text is a partial transcript of ["The Future of Programming"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecIWPzGEbFc), a conference given by [Robert "Uncle Bob" C. Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin).
The transcripted part starts at [1:14:25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecIWPzGEbFc&t=1h14m25s); bear in mind, however, that some parts are omitted in the transcript for brevity.

The part I picked talks about the role of software engineers in the modern world. In light of the [40-month prison sentence and $200.000 fine given to the main engineer](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/business/2017/08/26/vw-engineer-receives-40-month-prison-sentence-role-emissions/) involved in the Volkswagen scandal, I think the topic is now more relevant than ever.

<sub>(If you are a programmer / developer / software engineer of any kind and you haven't listened to this, I really *really* recommend you [start listening from here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecIWPzGEbFc&t=1h10m38s) -- it's only 8 minutes.)</sub>

Now, the text:

> We rule the world.
>   The world doesn't know this yet. We don't quite know it yet.
>   Other people *believe* that they rule the world, but they write the rules down and they hand them to us, and then *we* write the rules, that go into the machines, that execute everything that happens on this planet.
>   And one day, one of us is going to do something dumb (and maybe not even that dumb), and the result will be a catastrophe where tens of thousands of people die.
>   And when this happens, they will point their fingers right at us, and they will ask us the question: "How could you have let this happen?"
>
> <sub>(458 letters)</sub>

Example, non-golfed, translation:

> Nosotros regulamos el mundo.
>  El mundo no se ha enterado de esto aún. Nosotros no nos hemos enterado del todo aún.
>  Otras personas *se creen* que ellas regulan el mundo, pero escriben las reglas y luego nos las dan, y entonces nosotros escribimos las reglas que van en las máquinas que ejecutan todo lo que sucede en este planeta.
>  Y un día, uno de nosotros va a hacer algo estúpido (y quizá no tan estúpido), y el resultado será una catástrofe donde decenas de miles de personas mueran.
>  Y cuando esto pase, apuntarán su dedo índice hacia nosotros, y nos harán la pregunta: "¿Cómo habéis podido dejar que pase esto?".
>  
>  <sub>(484 letters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters?
Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### <strike>229 209 187 183 166 160 152 145 137 125 117 99</strike> 86 caracteres

> Amos, cándidos, del mundo, lo motorizamos como dice quien cree regir. Si un ¿error? mata a mil, pedirán razones.

Explicaciones:

- "amos del mundo": paso del "regir" (verbo) al "amos" (sustantivo). A fin de cuentas, los que son amos de algo son los que lo gobiernan.
- "cándidos": poco advertidos. Sin ser conscientes de lo que pasa en realidad (que gobernamos el mundo). Como más adelante se dice "quien cree regir", se entiende que ni nosotros ni quien cree regir sabe que en realidad nosotros gobernamos el mundo.
- "lo motorizamos": "motorizar" es "dar medios mecánicos de tracción", es decir, mover algo usando una máquina. En este caso ese "algo" es "el mundo" (referenciado por "lo").
- "como dice": la palabra (escrita, se supone) de los regentes es la ley, las normas, las reglas.
- "si un error...": uso una condicional para teorizar sobre qué pasaría en caso de un evento futuro. El original da por supuesto que ese evento pasará antes o después.
- "error": el original no habla de errores, pero sí de catástrofes, y desde luego una catástrofe no se provoca sin al menos un error de por medio (sea intencionado o no). El original habla simplemente de "something dumb", lo cual yo interpreto de forma benigna como "meterá la pata tontamente". Se entiende que es un un error de quien pasa las reglas a las máquinas, es decir, nosotros.
- "¿error?": el original sugiere que el error puede ser algo no hecho a propósito... o sí. Se pone pues "error" entre signos de interrogación para indicar que el error puede serlo o no (copio la idea de @fedorqui).
- "mata a mil": implícitamente se refiere a personas. Y si mil mueren se entiende que es una catástrofe. Se usa el singular al entender que con que mueran mil ya es una catástrofe, no tienen por qué ser miles.
- "pedirán": implícitamente se entiende que se dirigirán a nosotros (nos señalarán) y nos preguntarán.
- "razones": querrán saber la causa, el motivo, la razón por la que han muerto miles, y por ende por qué ha sucedido (dejamos que pasara).

La segunda frase está dada la vuelta para poner énfasis en el contraste entre los que hacen las reglas y los que las pasan a las máquinas.

---

**Descargo de responsabilidad:** Por debajo de la edición de 137 caracteres entramos ya en el terreno de los dobles saltos mortales con tirabuzón.

Comment: Ese **(o no)** no termina de transmitir el significado completo de "**(and maybe not even that dumb)**". A mi parecer, vendría a significar algo así como **(o no tan tonto)**. El problema radica en que tal y como lo has escrito, parece que diga que alguien puede hacer algo tonto, o puede no hacerlo.

Comment: @Shirkam estamos de acuerdo, llevo un tiempo dándole vueltas a cómo reorganizar esa frase para que quede más clara sin tener que recurrir a más caracteres.

Comment: Me gusta el cambio de lugar de *tonto*. Como comentario para reducir tamaño, ¿porqué no cambiar *Un día alguno cometerá* por *Algún día se cometerá*? Queda implícito que solo alguien que pueda cometer el error (ie: un ingeniero de software) puede ser la causa del mismo.

Comment: ¡No puede ser!. Estoy teniendo una sensación de *déjà vu*, igual que en el anterior juego con @walen, no hay un momento de paz.

Answer (score 4):

### <strike>225 184 178 164 158 147 141 134 125 116</strike> 92 caracteres

Cambio totalmente de tercio porque ya estamos a otro nivel. Espero poder justificar una mutilación de palabras tan atroz:

> Somos amos ajenos, ponemos leyes de falsos amos en supermáquinas. Una ¿memez? matará a miles y nos pedirán cuentas.

**ajeno:** Que no tiene conocimiento de algo, o no está prevenido de lo que ha de suceder.

Uso la palabra **supermáquinas** para expresar que son máquinas extraordinarias, capaces de todo.

Comment: Qué bien girada la parte inicial para dejarlo en "... los que creen mandar".

Comment: Me cuesta ver _nos dirán: dejasteis que pasara_ como sinónimo de _nos preguntarán que por qué dejasteis que pasara_.

Comment: Lo veía más como una pregunta retórica cuando en realidad nos acusan de haber provocado el desastre. Pero igual tengo que darle una vuelta

Comment: Sí, probablemente sea válido. Veamos qué opina @walen, que es quien nos... _rige_.

Comment: Ok. Veré que puedo hacer con esa primera frase.

Comment: Es posible que invirtiendo el orden se entienda mejor. Hecho.

Comment: Lo uso como sinonimo de *ignorante* que ya se ha usado por aquí, igual que *ignaro*.

Answer (score 4):

#### <s>189 182 171 155</s> 151 caracteres

> Nos, reyes sin saberlo e ignotos. Los que creen serlo definen reglas, que damos a quien todo hace: las máquinas. Pasará algo ¿bobo?, fatal: miles de muertos. Nos inquirirán: "¿cómo lo aprobasteis?".

- [Me descubro ante](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17176/1674) Carlos Alejo con su sugerencia de [*ignorantes e ignorados*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39866518#39866518) para la parte inicial. Contemplé *Ni él mundo ni nos lo sabemos, pero lo reinamos* o *Somos reyes desconocidos*. Después cambié *ignorados* por [*ignotos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KwHr6IH): *1. adj. No conocido ni descubierto* e *ignorantes* por *sin saberlo*. Así queda claro que reinan sin saberlo ni que se sepa.
- Tonto, bobo... todo define *dumb*.
- Catastrófico, desastroso, fatal... son sinónimos.
- Reglas, leyes... todo es lo mismo.
- Aprobar, permitir... todo traduce *let something happen*.
- Escribir, definir... todo referido a establecer leyes.
- [*Nos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QdQLrAb) es sinónimo de *nosotros*.
- [Inquirir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LiuHrsz) lo uso para denotar que *se nos preguntará*.

Comment: Recuerdo que dijiste un día que no se te daba bien este juego, era broma ¿no?

Comment: @blonfu esto es porque aún no habéis cogido carrerilla. En cuanto lo hagáis, me veo de farolillo rojo :)

Comment: Nos, "usado en la actualidad solo por ciertas personas de muy elevado rango o dignidad, como reyes, papas u obispos". Dado que se da en el texto el tratamiento de "reyes" a los programadores, parece lógico usarlo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo gracias por validarlo. A todo esto, quién más elevado que los programadores :D

Comment: Muy buena. Creo que todavía tienes de donde recortar y ponerte en cabeza, tu estructura se presta bien a ello.

Comment: @walen de acuerdo. Tomo nota y edito.

Answer (score 3):

## 230 caracteres

> Ignora el mundo que nosotros lo regimos. Otros creen hacerlo, pero nos dan para escribir reglas para  máquinas que hacen de todo en el mundo.
> Un día se hará algo quizá no tan tonto pero que causará decenas de miles de muertos. Entonces nos señalarán y dirán: Por qué dejasteis que pasara?

Answer (score 3):

**<strike>188</strike> <strike>169</strike> <strike>144</strike> <strike>141</strike> <strike>122</strike> 89 caracteres**

> Movemos el mundo ocultos, ignaros, dando leyes de seudojefes a equipos. Y tras hecho (¿bobo?), matanza para argüir

Lo dijo Carlos Alejo... vamos con triple mortal sin agua en la piscina, a seguir replanteando recursos para @walen en el último minuto

- Al usar el mover, se toma con su cuarta acepción (causa u ocasión)
- se determina que habrá un hecho, no necesariamente un error
- al tener que argüir, se requiere haber sido señalado

Comment: ¿ *Ignaros* significa algo o es un error y querías poner *ignorados*?

Comment: @blonfu pues parece que no. Ignaro significa "que no tiene noticia de las cosas". No queda muy claro en todo caso eso, ya que "no tener noticia de las cosas" parece implicar que "mandamos sin saber realmente lo que pasa en el mundo" más que "mandamos sin saber que lo hacemos". Una palabra interesante, en todo caso, al igual que "dizque": "al parecer, presuntamente". Luego "los dizque jefes" son "los que parecen jefes". Me parece una traducción muy original y competitiva, mis felicitaciones.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Es cierto, quizá escribí mal al buscar la palabra porque no la había encontrado. ¡Buena jugada!

Answer (score 2):

### 88 caracteres

> No lo saben, ni nos. Dominamos. Automatizamos la ley de quien cree regir. Al cagarla y morir miles, nos culparán.

No creo pasarme mucho más que algunas respuestas anteriores, pero por los comentarios veo que necesito justificar algunas decisiones.

He aceptado algunas críticas de mis versiones anteriores. *Nos* viene prestado de fedorqui.

---

> And one day, one of us is going to do something dumb (and maybe not even that dumb)

Para mí está clarísimo que está hablando de una cagada. Igual una cagadilla, pero *not even that* significa *apenas* (diminutivo), no *ni siquiera*.

---

> And when this happens, they will point their fingers right at us, and they will ask us the question: "How could you have let this happen?"

La pregunta me parece retórica. Los políticos cuando señalan con el dedo y hacen preguntas así no es (salvo alguna excepción honorable) porque quieren saber la respuesta sino porque quieren dejar claro ante el pueblo que la responsabilidad no es suya.

Comment: Por mi parte me uno a los aplausos de @walen, y me permito añadir que deberías explicar por qué omites la parte final que implica el que "nos preguntarán por qué dejamos que sucediera". Simplemente dices "nos culparán", pero no creo que eso implique lo de "querrán saber por qué pasó". Vista tu capacidad de síntesis no creo tampoco que te suponga mucho más texto.

Comment: Añadir también que te recomendamos que uses el [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/) para contar caracteres, ya que los signos de puntuación no entran en el conteo. Te he corregido la puntuación.

Comment: @walen, he quitado los dos puntos a coste de una letra. En cuanto a "*not even that dumb*", discrepamos en nuestra interpretación del inglés.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, es que no creo que quisieran saber por qué pasó. He optado por una interpretación de lo que quieren conseguir con la pregunta.

Comment: A mi las explicaciones me convencen, muy buena jugada. Pero hay una cosa que no veo clara, ignoto es algo oculto, desconocido; puede valer para *The world doesn't know this yet* pero no para *We don't quite know it yet*.

Comment: @blonfu, cierto.

Comment: @walen, if something you do kills people and you say it isn't an error, I'll take that as an admission that you *intended* to kill them. Your argument from Asimov's laws seems to me to be full of holes: for a start, that isn't even the correct statement of the 1st law; moreover, the point of the Robots stories (40 years ago!) was to show how the 3 laws were deficient, so adopting them now would be a very dumb mistake. My impression is that the author qualifies *dumb* to make the point that the error might be something as small as a `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Si no hay acuerdo @walen manda, como dicen las [reglas del juego](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/14069). Si le haces caso y editas esa parte ganas.