# Concordancia del verbo en sujetos compuestos

Tags: verbos, conjugación, concordancia-verbal

En el juego de *translation golf* de [esta semana](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22076/14069) me ha surgido una duda al escribir esta frase:

> Ni nosotros ni el mundo **sabe** aún que lo gobernamos

¿Está bien? ¿O sería así?:

> Ni nosotros ni el mundo **sabemos** aún que lo gobernamos

¿Cómo se decide qué conjugación lleva el verbo? ¿Concordaría con *nosotros* o con *el mundo*? ¿Cambiaría algo si dijera "ni el mundo ni nosotros"?

Comment: Alternativa 1 **Ni nosotros sabemos ni(y) el mundo (tampoco) sabe....** Alternativa 2 **Ni nosotros ni el mundo sabemos...** Siempre se debe conservar la coherencia/consistencia.

Comment: *ni* equivale a *y* (solo con valor negativo).  Por tanto, debe concordar como si fuese *y*.

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios, me ha quedado más claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El la página de [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Concordancia_entre_sujeto_y_verbo) que trata de la concordancia verbal dice:

> En general, cuando hay varios sujetos, aunque esté cada uno en
>   singular, la concordancia debe hacerse con el verbo en plural.

Y además:

> Si los sujetos son de distinta persona, el verbo concuerda en plural
>   con la persona que tenga prioridad (la primera persona tiene prioridad
>   sobre la segunda y tercera; y la segunda, sobre la tercera).

Por lo tanto en mi frase el verbo debe ir en plural y al haber un pronombre en primera persona el verbo irá en primera persona.

En el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5) también tenemos información al respecto de este tema:

> **c)** Si entre dos o más elementos coordinados figura un pronombre de
>   segunda persona (y ninguno de primera), la concordancia con el verbo y
>   con los demás pronombres se establece en segunda persona del plural o,
>   en las zonas del mundo hispánico donde no se usa el pronombre
>   vosotros, sino ustedes, en tercera persona del plural: *«La niña y tú
>   cobraréis lo que es vuestro»* (Leguina Nombre [Esp. 1992]); *«Murphy y
>   tú son unos testigos peligrosísimos»* (VLlosa Fiesta [Perú 2000]); si
>   hay un pronombre de primera persona, la concordancia se establece en
>   primera persona del plural: *«¿Te acuerdas de aquel día en que bailamos
>   Chema, tú y yo?»* (Diosdado Trescientos [Esp. 1991]).

Por lo tanto:

`Ni nosotros ni el mundo sabe aún que lo gobernamos`   ❌  Mal

`Ni nosotros ni el mundo sabemos aún que lo gobernamos`  ✔️ Bien

Answer (score 3):

La verdad es que a mí me pasaba lo mismo que a ti con las frases que presentas como ejemplo, pero el comentario de @guifa da la puntilla. ¿Y si la frase fuese afirmativa?

> Nosotros y el mundo **sabemos** que lo gobernamos.

Aquí parece claro que hay que usar la primera persona del plural, ya que todos (nosotros incluidos) sabemos que lo gobernamos. Más claro queda también si le damos la vuelta a los elementos del sujeto en la frase original:

> Ni el mundo ni nosotros **sabemos** aún que lo gobernamos.

Si escribimos "ni el mundo ni nosotros sabe" la oración parece claramente incorrecta. Y desde luego, el número del verbo no debería cambiar al alterar simplemente el orden de los elementos del sujeto o al pasar la oración a afirmativa.

Por tanto, el tiempo correcto (tal y como comentó @DGaleano) es el que mantiene la concordancia: **sabemos**.

Comment: Gracias, queda aclarado el asunto. Publico otra respuesta con más irformación que he encontrado