# Is there some kind of "precedence" when using multiple persons with a single verb?

Tags: persona-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

Let's say we have this:

> Yo sé.
>   Tú sabes.
>   Él sabe.
>   Nosotros sabemos.
>   Vosotros sabéis.
>   Ellos saben.

So far so good. However:

> Tú y yo sabemos. --> Person: Nosotros?
>   Tú y él sabéis.  --> Person: Vosotros?
>   Nosotros y ellos sabemos.  --> Person: Nosotros, why not ellos?
>   Tú y todo el mundo sabéis. --> Person: Vosotros, why not ellos o nosotros?

It looks like there is an established order between persons, is it so?
How do we know which one to use when there's many different persons?
E.g. *Ellos, yo y tú mismo {sabemos? sabeis? sabes?}*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Castellano

Sí, hay una prioridad con las personas a la hora de concordar el verbo, lo he descubierto investigando para [mi pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22087/concordancia-del-verbo-en-sujetos-compuestos) sobre sujetos compuestos. La primera persona tiene prioridad sobre las demás y la segunda la tiene sobre la tercera.

En [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Concordancia_entre_sujeto_y_verbo) leemos:

> Si los sujetos son de distinta persona, el verbo concuerda en plural
>   con la persona que tenga prioridad (la primera persona tiene prioridad
>   sobre la segunda y tercera; y la segunda, sobre la tercera).
>
> *Juan y yo iremos al cine, así que tú y Olga tendréis que esperar un rato hasta que lleguemos.*

---

#### English

Yes, there is a priority with people when it comes to agreeing with the verb. I found out while investigating for [my question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22087/concordancia-del-verbo-en-sujetos-compuestos) about compound subjects. The first person has the priority over the other, as well as the second over the third.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to emphasise.

Tu y yo sabemos = Nostros sabemos.

The thing is that when you say "nosotros" it could be an unlimited number of people. Let's put an example:

- Me and you know he is cheating on her .- Here the emphasis is that you and me know something. I am not talking about other people
- We know he is cheating on her. .- Me and you know it but there could be other that know it too.

**There is not and established order between people**. However, as @blonfu points in the comments, the use "yo" the last is a respect formality, not gramatical rule.

Therefore, normally the rule is to put "I" **(YO) is the last**.

Example:

You could never say "Yo y tu sabemos", the proper way to say it is "Tu y yo"; "Yo y ellos pensamos..." the proper way is "Ellos y yo pensamos...".

If you can't say " Ellos, yo y tu sabemos.." the right way is:

"Ellos, tu y yo sabemos".

Comment: "(YO) is allways the last". Use *yo* the last is a respect formality, not gramatical rule: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=yo