# ¿Qué quiere decir "ignaro"? ¿Cómo se construye?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, palabras-raras

Leo en [un artículo](http://www.lavanguardia.com/politica/20180521/443748016974/forza-italia-enric-juliana-albert-rivera-ciudadanos.html):

> Berlusconi irrumpió en política rompiendo los atriles. El magnate se paseaba por el escenario con un micro inalámbrico como si estuviera en un plató de televisión. ¡Populista!, gritaban sus adversarios, **ignaros** de la novedad histórica que tenían ante sus narices. La televisión se iba a comer la política. Y después vendría internet. En eso estamos. Toda la política es hoy formato televisivo, encapsulado para la red.

Mirando en el DLE veo que efectivamente esta palabra existe:

> [**ignaro, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KvdESnk)
>
> ```
> Del lat. ignārus.
> ```
>
> 1. adj. Que no tiene noticia de las cosas.

Pero nunca la había oído y en este mismo contexto siempre había dicho *desconocedores* o *ignorantes* (en su acepción primigenia de desconocer algo, no la peyorativa de no saber nada de nada).

Por ello, me pregunto: ¿en qué contextos se puede utilizar? ¿Qué tan común es? ¿Cuál es su etimología?

Comment: Hoy aprendimos una nueva. +1. El ngram es interesante....desde 1960 empezó a desaparecer.. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ignaro&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cignaro%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @DGaleano curioso! En 1734 se marcaba como _en voz de raro uso_, luego se recuperó para finalmente caer otra vez en desuso.

Comment: A mí me encanta, es una de mis palabras favoritas sobre todos porque suena mucho peor de lo que significa. En mi clase de matemáticas quien "olvida" la tarea (deberes) es declarado *ignaro* del grupo. Es siempre un momento "enseñable" al principio del curso precisamente porque al "sonar" insultante, incentiviza a los estudiantes y en particular al aludido a investigar el significado original. (Saludos a mis alumnos de los futuros cursos Algebra 301 y Cálculo diferencial 501) que encontrarán esta pregunta el próximo semestre.

Comment: quizá debiste revisar los translation golf... en algún juego usé la palabra https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22076/translation-golf-xvii-we-rule-the-world/22089#22089 que si bien no respondía por completo la pregunta, te daba una base inicial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dice la entrada de la RAE, viene del latín *ignārus*, es un sinónimo perfecto de *ignorante* (< īgnōrante / īgnōrantī < īgnōrāns< īgnōrō < īgnārus), y, por [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ignaro%2Bignara%2Cignorante&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3), parece muy poco común. Aún en el siglo XVIII los diccionarios dicen que era

> "Lo mismo que Ignorante. **En voz de raro uso.**"
>
> - Academia Autoridades, 1734

Comment: Qué curioso pues que _aguante_ tres siglos siendo de raro uso.

Comment: En la voz del latin es facil identificarlo con i-gno , aunque por otro lado puede ser confundido con sanscrito ignis  que significa fuego