# ¿Palabra para describir que una persona ignora un tema?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Estoy buscando una palabra para expresar que una persona no tiene conocimiento sobre algo.
He pensado que quizá "[neófito](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QOTvoZe)" podría describirlo, pero no me convence.

¿Qué otra palabra sería la mejor para este concepto?

Answer (score 5):

Se me ocurre ***ignaro***:

> [**ignaro, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KvdESnk)
>   `Del lat. ignārus.`
>
> 1. adj. Que no tiene noticia de las cosas.

Ya hablamos de esta palabra en [¿Qué quiere decir "ignaro"? ¿Cómo se construye?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26343/1674), donde también se mencionó *ignorante*:

> [**ignorante**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KwE5Zd7)
>   `De ignorar y -nte; lat. ignōrans, -antis.`
>
> 1. adj. Que ignora o desconoce algo.
>   2. adj. Que carece de cultura o conocimientos. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.

Sin embargo, no me convence tanto porque su acepción común es la 2.ª, como sustantivo, y tiene una connotación peyorativa más que descriptiva.

Comment: Gracias fedorqui. No conocía ignaro 

Answer (score 5):

Otra alternativa podría ser [**lego**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=lego)

> 2. adj. Falto de instrucción, ciencia o conocimientos.

especialmente en la forma "**lego en la materia**".

Comment: Rotten gracias. Es cierto, no habia caído en "lego"

Answer (score 3):

La tercera acepción de [profano, na](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UHbgpKm) es

> 3. adj. Que carece de conocimientos y autoridad en una materia. U. t. c. s.

que cuadra con el término solicitado (y está relacionada con el aspecto religioso, como el "neófito" propuesto en la pregunta).

Esta acepción parece que no cuadra con las demás, pero es que por extensión de los otros significados:

> llamamos también profano al que no está iniciado en los misterios de la religión, o no los conoce; así como dando mayor latitud a esta palabra, calificamos de profano al que desconoce una ciencia, una materia, aunque esta no sea sagrada.
>
> Fuente: [¿QUE QUIERE DECIR PROFANO EN LA MATERIA?](http://pinceladasdecultura.blogspot.com/2009/09/que-quiere-decir-profano-en-la-materia.html)

Comment: Diego enorme! "Profano" se trata del término que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Maite? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 2):

Definición de Neófito

Este vocablo proviene del griego, concretamente de la palabra neophytos. El prefijo neo quiere decir nuevo y phyton significa planta. Por lo tanto, etimológicamente significa recién plantado. Un persona es considerado un neófito cuando se encuentra en los inicios de una actividad o disciplina y todavía no la conoce a fondo. Se podria usar, soy neofito en la materia, cuando no sabes de un tema especifico.

Comment: Bienvenida a [spanish.se]! Por favor, añade la fuente de esa definición; es [obligatorio](/help/referencing) aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Las posibilidades dependen mucho de la intención de uso y el contexto de la frase (cuán coloquial o culta, o para qué audiencia esté dirigida)

De alguien podemos decir que es

> ***Ignorante***, ***profano***, ***lego***, ***no-versado***, ***inculto*** o ***nulo*** [en cualquier materia o tema]

En la misma linea que ***neófito*** —para implicar ***no iniciado*** o ***aprendiz***— también se podría usar

> ***Novicio***  o ***Novato***
>   Por "Nuevo o principiante en cualquier arte, facultad o materia" 
>   https://dle.rae.es/?id=QfroCHB
>   https://dle.rae.es/?id=QezMkWD

Comment: neófito conoce el tema, pero poco. No conocer una tema  no implica inculto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo propongo [iletrado, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ky440Ll), que el DRAE define como sinónimo de [analfabeto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2VcZnaQ), y este a su vez (aparte de "Que no sabe leer ni escribir", que es la acepción que todos nos viene a la cabeza primero) como

> 2. adj. Ignorante, sin cultura, o profano *en alguna disciplina*.

Answer (score 0):

Algo que no ofendería sería

**principiante**

Es alguien que apenas empieza a aprender algo sobre el tema en cuestión.

[DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UC2a3R1):

> 2. adj. Que empieza a aprender o ejercer un oficio o una profesión, o a realizar una actividad. U. m. c. s.

Ruiz usó este término en su serie *Cuba Para Principiantes*, etc.  Es un eufemismo para *idiotas*.

Comment: Aunque principiante pueda haber sido eufemísticamente usado para enmascarar idiota, el empleo del término, así _suavizado decorosamente_ por esa vía, es una manera poco precisa de relacionarlo

Comment: @user2325442 - Pues todo depende del contexto, ¿no?

Comment: Si exacto, creo que todas las contestaciones cubren el rango de posibilidades. Cual sea el término adecuado depende del contexto (que no está incluido en la pregunta)

Comment: es buena la referencia a la elección del título, sobre todo porque el término original en inglés "dummy" resulta muy ofensivo

Comment: @user2325442 - También "idiota" -- hay una serie "X for dummies" y otra muy parecida "Y for idiots".

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren un par de expresiones que no sé si encajan exactamente con la pregunta.

**iliterato, ta**

> 1. adj. p. us. Ignorante y no versado en ciencias ni letras humanas.

**indocto, ta**

> 1. adj. Falto de instrucción, inculto. U. t. c. s.

Comment: No, ignora algo no quire decir eso.