# What does 'se me fue' mean?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, coloquialismos

What does 'se me fue' mean?

Does it literally mean **'it escaped me'** or is there another colloquial meaning?

Comment: Can you please provide some context? Otherwise the answers might not be accurate...

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! The sentence does not seem to have a second meaning, but it can be used in a wide variety of situations. We want to help you, but we really need a larger context in order to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 5):

The expression **"se me fue"** without any context could mean different things. Maybe you can give more context about it. Nevertheless, here are some examples that could be useful for you to understand it.

**1. Break up a relationship**

> - Maria: I've been so selfish and I lost him.
>   - Isabel: Don't be so hard on yourself.
>
> - Maria: ¡He sido muy egoista y se me fue (o lo perdí)!
>   -  Isabel: ¡No seas dura contigo misma!

**2. Forgetting something spontaneously**

> - José: Hey Juan, did you go to the party yesterday?
>   - Juan: Damn, I completely forgot it!
>
> - José: Hey Juan, ¿fuiste a la fiesta ayer?
>   - Juan: Demonios*, ¡se me fue completamente!
>
> - *Demonios, can be replaced by local or regional expresion. It depends on the culture.*

**3. Someone passed away**

> - Abigail: My dad passed away. I can't overcome it.
>   - Carlos: I am so sorry to hear that. Be strong!
>
> - Abigail: Mi padre se me fue. No puedo superarlo.
>   - Carlos: ¡Cuánto lo siento! ¡Sé fuerte!

**4. Losing something suddenly**

> - Roberto: Holly s**t! I lost my wedding ring. It fell down into the sink!
>   - Rosa: Oh no! I will call the plumber right away!
>
> - Roberto: Mi**da, ¡Se me fue el anillo de matrimonio por el lavatorio!
>   - Rosa: ¡Oh no! ¡Llamaré al fontanero inmediatamente!

**5. Losing control**

> - Christian: Dude, you hit that car so hard!
>   - Jorge: I lost control. The road is slippery!
>
> - Christian: Amigo*, ¡chocaste al otro carro muy fuerte!
>   - Jorge: Se me fue. La carretera está muy resbalosa.
>
> - *Amigo, can be replaced by local or regional expression. It depends on the culture.*

**6 Missing something**

> - Esteban: Oh no! I missed the bus again!
>
> - Esteban: ¡Oh no! ¡Se me fue (o perdí) el bus de nuevo!

Answer (score 3):

In Spain it is quite common, in unformal conversations, to say *se me fue* as a short way to say *se me fue* either *la cabeza*, *la olla*, *la pinza* or any kind of object that relates to the mind of oneself.

So you would listen:

> - ¿Por qué no viniste ayer a la cena?
>   - Ostras... ¡se me fue!

Meaning:

> - Why didn't you come yesterday to the dinner?
>   - Oh my gosh, I completely forgot about it.

Further reading: [¿Cuál es el origen de “irse la olla” o “irse la pinza”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13638/1674)

Comment: There is also the situation when you are about to say something and you get distracted an loose the idea. Then you say "se me fue (la idea)" In Colombia many will say "se me fue la paloma"

Comment: "Se me fue", "Se me fue la idea", "Se me fue lo que iba a decir", are all possible. Sometimes you can use "escapar" instead.

Answer (score -1):

Se me fue means "oops"

I am from Southamerica, and "ostras" has several meanings like many words in Spanish. If you use it unproperly this word has very offensive meanings, so take care when you use it.

Comment: I'm form southamerica too and even if "ostras" sounds ridiculous to me I won't beat you, and BTW "se me fue" means a lot more than "oops"

Comment: Well I think you known what "ostras" have a very offesive meaning for some people when is not used in a properly way.

Comment: I understand that too but that is not what you are explaining in your answer. You are just saying that in southamerica people get beaten by say ostas and that is not true.  Your answers should provide context and if possible references. Please read  http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Let me explain better, i will fix my answer

Comment: Maybe you should explain those "offensive meanings" and elaborate more the meaning and possible connotations in a specific country. I'm sure it is not the same in every single country.